# Google Cloud Deployed Files not seen

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to see the deployed the files in google cloud console?
I use 'goapp deploy'
I can open google shell but I don't know where to check.
When I check the google shell, it looks like Linux platform but I can't find any deployed files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Shell is just a temporary machine that Google provides you for FREE in order to help you to interact with your google cloud platform projects. You will never find the deployed code on this machine. If you deployed your code on a Compute Engine machine you can find the code on the compute engine instance. If you deployed your code on App Engine you can use this command to download yuor app code https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appcfg-arguments#download_app

Google Cloud Platform provides an interesting feature that you may want to check out to handle your source code. Google Cloud Source Repositories are fully-featured, private Git repositories hosted on Google Cloud Platform.

https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/